# regexp for selecting a line from file based on a value

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a line from a file and replace it:

Suppose this the content in the file: '547714,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'

Based on 547714 i need to select and replace the complete line

i am using this regexp: `'/^.*547714.*$/';`

But its not selecting anything.

Comment: Your regex has a different number in it - is this intended?  That's why it won't match.

Comment: I have updated the regexp but still its not comming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex looks OK. However, you need to tell the regex engine to allow the `^` and `$` anchors to match the start and end of each line (and not the entire input string). That's what the `/m` modifier is for. Also, word boundaries (`\b`) are a good idea here to avoid substring matches.

So I'd suggest

```
regex = '/^.*\b345345\b.*$/m';
```

This will match an entire line containing `345345` (but it won't match a line like `1,53453456,4,5,0`).

Answer (score 0):

`^.*547714.*$`

Seems to work for me, perhaps the engine is also taking into account the `/`?

Comment: Nope, those are the PHP regex delimiters.

Comment: @Tim - My mistake, it's been years since I've touched PHP